# Splitting each line of an array into a String

Tags: java, arrays, string, minecraft-forge

I'm making an minecraft-forge mod and I'm having some problems with my config file. I used Configuration#getStringList which allows other people to add a String[] to the config file, so I'm using that to get an block from the array, for example if someone writes minecraft:gold_ore the Block#getBlockFromName works fine because in the array there's only that and nothing else, but if I place minecraft:gold_ore and minecraft:diamond_ore in the next line, it crashes because Block#getBlockFromName reads the String I sent him so he reads it like this minecraft:gold_oreminecraft:diamond_ore (which causes the crash because the block with than name doesn't exist) instead of it reading minecraft:gold_ore and than minecraft:diamond_ore. I basically want to split each line of that config to a separate String or somehow read each line separately.
This is how the configuration file looks like:

```
# Configuration file
"ore generation" {
    S:ore_to_gen <
        minecraft:gold_ore
        minecraft:diamond_ore
     >
```

so if I just enter minecraft:gold_ore and delete minecraft:diamond_ore the world loads normally and the generation works, this is the config class:

```
    public class ConfigCustomOreGen {

        public static Configuration configCustomWorld;
        private static File configCustomOreGenDir;

        public static String oreToReplace;

        public static final String WORLD = "Ore Generation";


        public static void init(File oreGenDir) {
            oreGenDir = new File(oreGenDir, Constants.MODID + "/" + "world");
            oreGenDir.mkdir();
            ConfigCustomOreGen.configCustomOreGenDir = oreGenDir;
            ConfigCustomOreGen.configCustomWorld = new Configuration(new File(oreGenDir, "Custom-Ore-Generation.cfg"));

            String[] oreReplace = configCustomWorld.getStringList("ore_to_gen", WORLD, EMPTY_STRING, "ore which should have custom ore gen\n");

            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < oreReplace.length; i++) {
                strBuilder.append(oreReplace[i]);
            }
            oreToReplace = strBuilder.toString();
            Constants.LOGGER.info(oreToReplace + " " + strBuilder.toString());

            if (configCustomWorld.hasChanged()) {
                configCustomWorld.save();
            }
        }

        private final static String[] EMPTY_STRING = {};
}
```

And for the generation I just use my custom WorldGenMinable which works because it worked with minecraft:gold_ore and any blocks I give it under the ore variable, the problem happens when the Block#getBlockFromName reads a block name which doesn't exist:

```
public class CustomOreGen implements IWorldGenerator {

    @Override
    public void generate(Random random, int chunkX, int chunkZ, World world, IChunkGenerator chunkGenerator, IChunkProvider chunkProvider) {
        Block ore = Block.getBlockFromName(ConfigCustomOreGen.oreToReplace);
        generateOre(ore, world, random, chunkX, chunkZ, 20, 180, 8, 24, 8);
    }

    private void generateOre(Block ore, World world, Random random, int chunkX, int chunkZ, int minY, int maxY, int minVeinSize, int maxVeinSize, int chancesToSpawn) {
        int heightRange = maxY - minY;
        BlockPos blockpos = new BlockPos((chunkX * 16) + random.nextInt(16), minY + random.nextInt(heightRange), (chunkZ * 16) + random.nextInt(16));

        if (world.provider.getDimension() == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < chancesToSpawn; i++) {
                WorldGenIngotterMinable generator = new WorldGenIngotterMinable(ore, minVeinSize, maxVeinSize, Blocks.AIR);
                generator.generate(world, random, blockpos);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In which package that configuration class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply split the String on each newline-character. Just make sure you use the correct newline-character used in that file.

It might look something like this: `String[] oresToReplace = oreToReplace.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"))`

Comment: The problem is to I need an String and not an String[] in Block#getBlockFromName so how should I get that? I always get java.lang.NullPointerException because that name doesn't exist so it cannot generate the block in the world. But when I print it out with the line seperator it prints out [minecraft:gold_ore, minecraft:diamond_ore]

Comment: getBlockForName I would guess returns one Block, and takes one Name as an argument. Pass it one Name after another to get all the Blocks you need.

Comment: How should I pass it one by one? I'm thinking about getting to the comma and copying everything before it into the getBlockFromName but how should I do it?

Comment: The output from your last attempt was formatted. Look up "java foreach" that should help.

Comment: Looks like its working thank you for all your help :) I just placed the foreach loop in the generate method of my WorldGeneration class.